# How can I save app status in Appdesigner?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

Is there a built-in way to save/load (Serialize/deserialize) the whole UI in MATLAB Appdesigner?

**Background:**

I want to add save/load feature to an app. I think that since the App itself is an object of a class inherited from `matlab.apps.AppBase`, I may be able to serialize the whole object into some file on the hard disk. Then, when I want to restore this file I will deserialize it to recover the previously saved status of the app.

This should save all components properties in addition to all app class properties.

Is this possible? How?